# Ignore Greek Letter Representation in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to make a variable with the subscript `pi` on it as follows:

```
r_pi = sp.symbols('r_pi')
```

[image]

When displayed, the symbol uses the greek letter π as the subscript but my intention in this case is to actually just use "pi" as if it is not a greek letter. Is there to make sympy ignore converting this symbol to a greek letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mathrm` in the name:

[image]